# How to find match of words with reoccuring character in a file

Tags: grep, expression

It might seems like a question that would already have been answered before so pardon me if it's the case, but I can't seems to find a clear answer or an explanation on how to find words in a file with a specified number of repeated character, (ex: words containing 3 times the character '-', such as 'long-and-complex-word').

I'm aware that it is possible to use the command

```
grep-oE '.{n}'
```

To find words with consecutive repetition of character, but I'm looking for a way to find repetition of character in no particular order.

Here are the commands that I've tried that aren't working

```
grep -E '*[-]*[-]*[-]*' file
grep -Ex '* \-* \-* \ -*' file
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can close this post, I found the answer I was looking for: grep -E '(.*-){3}' file.

Comment: It would be safer to use `([^-]*-){3}`.

Comment: Please clarify: three or more times, or exactly three times? What do you consider to be words?